# Rails, tinymce-rails multiple images path breaking because of "../../../"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tinymce-rails

Hi everyone I am trying use tinymce-rails and and also have an upload form. This works really well since I can call the images anywhere. Just about everything is working great. The images upload, the tinymce styles stuff.

Now the weird thing is tinymce keeps adjusting the file paths to add "../../../" and this breaks the photos when editing the text. It would actually work fine if it would just go up one more "../" count on the edit page, the pathing does work on the show page.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any direction they can give me?

Comment: what html you are using to show images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can't know the source of this, I can provide a workaround.

In your model, let's call it `Post`, you might need to replace stuff to the field containing the html, let's call it `body`:

```
before_save {
    body.gsub!(/(\.\.\/)+/,"..\/")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I know id hadn't provided much information and your suggestion worked great. In the end this worked

`before_save :fix_photos`

`def fix_photos
   self.description.gsub!(/(\.\.\/)+/,"/")
end`